# R - 3 way table

Tags: r

I have the following table

```
Date   Visits  User
Feb1   10     1
Feb1   20     1
Feb1   100    2
Feb2   10     2
Feb3   34     6
```

I am trying to generate a stacked column chart where x-axis is Date and y-axis is Visits, column is stacked by number of visits by user on that day.  That is for Feb 1 it should show a column of height=130 where it has two parts, 100 by user 2 and 30 by user 1.

I understand that i should generate a table of this form:

```
         1   2   6
Feb 1   30  100
Feb 2        10
Feb 3            34
```

and then use the barplot function. Does R provide any easy functions to convert the first table into the second table format?  Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to use package `ggplot2` for this task.

```
library(ggplot2)
#assuming that data frame is named df
ggplot(df,aes(Date,Visits,fill=factor(User)))+geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To get data in the form that you were expecting, you can use `xtabs`:

```
> (temp <- xtabs(Visits ~ Date + User, SODF))
      User
Date     1   2   6
  Feb1  30 100   0
  Feb2   0  10   0
  Feb3   0   0  34
```

You need to *transpose* this data before you can use it with `barplot`:

```
barplot(t(temp), legend = TRUE, 
        col = c("skyblue", "grey", "palegreen"), 
        xlab = "Date", ylab = "Visits")
```

[image]